# output a sorted file in C using qsort

Tags: c

to read strings from a file and print the sorted output using qsort. So I write something like this:

```
int main()
{
  int n=0;
  int size=1;
  File *fp = fopen(args[0],"r");
  int c;
  char* inputFile;
  inputFile = char* malloc(size);
  if(fp==0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file!\n");
    return -1;
  else{
    do{
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if(size==1){
        inputFile[n]=c;
      }
      else{
        inputFile = char* realloc(inputFile, size+1);
        inputFile[n]=c;
      }
      n++;
      size++;
  }while(c!=EOF);
  qsort(inputFile, 1, size, compare);//I have implement the compare function correctly
  n=0;
  while(n<size){
    while(input[n]!='\0'){
       printf ("%d ",inputFile[n]);
       n++;
    }
    n++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So, if the input file is '\0vaaa\n\0ba\0\nabc', the program should output print:

```
abc
ba
vaaa
```

However, my code isn't working at all. I have check that the compare method return the correct result. Additionally, I just wonder if I implement the malloc-realloc correctly? Thx

Comment: when I try to input command ./test1.c testFile.txt it output nothing

Comment: `"Cannot open file!"` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  `man perror`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print strings, so replace:

```
printf ("%d ",inputFile[n]);
```

with

```
printf ("%s ",inputFile[n]);
```

But you may have other problems in your code..

Comment: And how do you handle NULL characters in the string?

Comment: `inputFile[n]` is just one char. You probably meant `printf ("%s ",inputFile);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is perhaps better to just `mmap(2)` the file into memory and not read it in painfully, but oh well.

Don't cast the result of `malloc(3)` and its ilk. Unneded, might mask mistakes.

`qsort(3)` sorts arrays (elements of *fixed* size). Create an array like `char *line[]`, set it up so each element points at the respective line. My qsort(3) manual page (from the Linux man-pages) has an example doing exactly this.

Comment: however, the size of the file isn't constant. one of the test case file will keep mutating(growing) when this program is executed. Since, C doen't have vector, so I use malloc and realloc

Comment: Sorting a file which is changing under your feet... see any problem with that proposition?

Comment: yep, but that's one of the requirement, kinda weird, isn't it

Comment: @EldwinH, if just _growing_ you can `mmap(2)` the file, create the array of pointers I mention in my answer (and count the number of strings in the same go), and sort the array of pointers. Any strings appended just won't be considered. You could even extend your already sorted array with any new strings and re-sort (but check that your `qsort(3)` doesn't behave badly in such a situation).

Answer (score 0):

Gah, I see a lot of errors in your code.

See this *small* example (compatible with C99 compilers). Note this is only part of your program. I've not used the `qsort` in this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i, length;
  int j = 0;
  FILE *f = fopen("nullfile.bin","r");
  while((i = fgetc(f)) != EOF) j++;
  rewind(f);
  int array[j];
  length = j;
  j = 0;
  while((i = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    array[j++] = i;
  fclose(f);
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(array[i] == '\0') { printf("\n"); continue; }
    printf("%c", array[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get rid of the `malloc()` completely and use variable length arrays. The code is much more simpler this way.

Comment: however, the size of one of the test file isn't fix. by the time the first loop is finished, a new string/character might be appended to the file

Comment: @EldwinH that is upto you to handle. It depends on how you take care of the "producer consumer" logic.